# How to get newly generated id on the MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the model that has multiple entities. For example I have an `order` that have `CustomerId` to foreign key. In the model I have some fields from the `order` and some fields from the `customer` entity. When I am saving new record I would like to save `customer` first, get newly generated identity value and put it to the `order` table. How to achieve that? I can do that by getting `MAX(ID)` from the `customer` table, however I am pretty sure that there is better way to handle that.

This is my controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create(OrderModels model, FormCollection form)
{
    try
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer() { FirstName = model.FirstName, MiddleName = model.MiddleName, SecondName = model.SecondName, Email = model.Email, PhoneNbr = model.PhoneNbr };
        int orderSource = Int32.Parse(form["OrderSourceList"]);
        int paymentType = Int32.Parse(form["PaymentTypeList"]);
        string warehouseGuid = form["Warehouses"];
        ProductLogic productLogic = new ProductLogic();
        Product product = productLogic.GetProductByArticle(model.Article);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder()
        {
            OrderNbr = model.OrderNbr,
            OrderSourceId = orderSource,
            NpWarehouseRef = new Guid(warehouseGuid),
            TTN = model.TTN,
            OrderStatusId = 1,
            PaymentTypeId = paymentType,
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        using (AccountingRepository repository = new AccountingRepository())
        {

            repository.AddOrUpdate<Customer>(customer);
            repository.AddOrUpdate<SalesOrder>(salesOrder);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

AccountingRepository has `dispose` method

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_context != null)
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My `Order` class:

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

```
namespace Accounting.Entity
{
    [Table("SalesOrder", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class SalesOrder
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

...
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

...
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        internal class Config : EntityTypeConfiguration<SalesOrder>
        {
            public Config()
            {

                HasRequired(r => r.Customer)
                   .WithMany(r => r.SalesOrder)
                   .HasForeignKey(r => r.CustomerId);



            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `Customer` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace Accounting.Entity
{
    [Table("Customer", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string SecondName { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNbr { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }


        public virtual HashSet<SalesOrder> SalesOrder { get; set; }

        internal class Config : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
        {
            public Config()
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using EF, it will take care of it for you, if you have navigation properties on  your models.

Comment: actually you use EF to handle the relations for you and you dont need to get last records or scopeidentity ...

Comment: I've modified the question and added controller and entity classes.

Comment: You just need to attach the customer entity to the order entity. The FK customer id should be handled for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Save the customer entity, and Entity Framework will back fill the PK property with it's ID. You can then use this for the order entity.

   ```
   db.Customers.Add(customer);
   db.SaveChanges();
   order.CustomerId = customer.Id; // has a value now
   ```
2. Just associate the customer with the order via a navigation property. When you save everything Entity Framework works out which relationships need to be saved first and then fills in the appropriate FK ids in the related entities.

   ```
   order.Customer = customer;
   db.Orders.Add(order);
   db.SaveChanges(); // customer is saved first and the id is set for order.CustomerId automatically
   ```

Comment: Could you please show an example? I tried to do:                 AccountingRepository repository = new AccountingRepository();
                repository.AddOrUpdate<Customer>(customer);
                repository.Save();
                repository.AddOrUpdate<SalesOrder>(salesOrder);
                repository.Save();
                repository.Dispose(); //and that did not help

Comment: See update above. If this isn't working with your repository methods, then something is not set up right in the repository.